# Separate author&public mvn projects or standard Magnolia bundle?

Tags: configuration, project, magnolia

What are the pros and cons between creating a custom bundle that has separate author and public webapps in a bundle and the standard bundle that has only one complete webapp (magnoliaAuthor) that is then partially copied to create the second webapp (magnoliaPublic)?

Considerations should be made for a typical setup, for example a web shop with lots of integration. Recommended characteristics to consider: security, ease of understanding the project structure/neatness, ease of development - code reuse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PRO: Having it separately is more appropriate if we might want to install some modules on the author instance only as they are relevant only to authors, or when they are in some way perceived as security-critical and not desired on the public instance.

CON: If different wars are required for the two environments then you would have to use that approach, but that is not ideal for a typical setup. It's possible to secure a module from starting on public by checking the flag. Every module has a module class where you can control how and when a module should be started.
It's not necessary to bloat the package to have author and public instances. The standard is to have a single war with multiple configurations. Starting from scratch, with an empty mangolia bundle you get this setup, to get separate a&p mvn projects, you have to duplicate the empty webapp project and customize them to obtain a separate public&author.

Relevant docs:

- [War file with multiple configurations](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS61/WAR+file+with+multiple+configurations)
- [Magnolia best practices from a SysAdmin point of view](http://pvnp.us/sysadmin-cfg.pdf) "should resist the temptation of using multiple war deployables, use one war with more config."
- [Example for separate maven modules](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/WIKI/Example+for+a+maven+based+magnolia+project)

Answer (score 0):

[The best practices from the Magnolia documentation](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS61/WAR+file+with+multiple+configurations).

Comment: Relevant documentation but doesn't answer the question, only describes why it is good and how is the creation of a single WAR file with multiple configurations implemented. Maybe its silence can be considered a con to the idea of having separate wars/maven-modules for author and public.

Comment: Having separate WAR files can be problematic from at least a maintenance perspective.  Imagine you have N different environments, with different repository configs, author vs. public, etc.  Do you want to compile that N times, or once? How can you know you are using the right versions of everything on the right machines? I've attached 10-ish slides from a workshop we gave on this a couple years ago here: http://pvnp.us/sysadmin-cfg.pdf - hope it helps.

Comment: In the one scenario I know of there are many (more dev, test, prod) enviromental configs by maven profile and magnolia properties that are sort of duplicated on the author and public maven modules. Its architect who is my adviser in Magnolia argues that it is more straightforward this way than having just one maven module for author+public. I'm in doubt if this project setup is a good practice to follow. Correct me if you could reformulate the question to better reflect this question.